# SAML Token generation for third party

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, sts-securitytokenservice, wif4.5

I need to create User Management Service which will be central point to authorize AD users for multiple applications. Applications can be both intranet or Internet, internal or external.

What I figured out it will be something like [Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3). But due to some requirements we doesn't want Identity server but custom STS (Security Token Service). 
 - We need to take input from 3rd parties credentials
 - validate in our Active Directory
 - generate & send SAML token to authenticated users.

I have looked into :

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/windows-identity-foundation-and-single-sign-on-sso/

http://garymcallisteronline.blogspot.in/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-4-adfs-20-and-3rd-party-sts.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx#singlesignon_topic9

https://coding.abel.nu/2014/08/kentor-authservices-saml2-owin-middleware-released/

But I am still confused how 3rd party will understand that SAML or need what to interpret that shared identity info.

- 3rd party app can be on any language other than .Net too
- they don't need to make change into their code/implementation.

Please suggest.

This is conceptual/architectural question so please don't advise to add code & then to offer help.